# Getting Ciphersuit error in liberty server

Tags: ssl, encryption, websphere-liberty

Below are my debug mode logs:

```
enter code here

Is initial handshake: true
main, setSoTimeout(0) called
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: SSL_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: SSL_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, SSLv3
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1490319829 bytes = { 83, 197, 91, 220, 29, 11, 103, 125, 151, 197, 221, 194, 108, 99, 155, 171, 151, 221, 122, 4, 193, 146, 218, 167, 165, 11, 84, 55 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
***
main, WRITE: SSLv3 Handshake, length = 55
main, received EOFException: error
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, called closeSocket()
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
java.lang.Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake in class com.fdc.to.net.http.HttpsComHandler
```

Because of this error I am not able to run my application.
Please help me If there is any solution for this issue.
I am using IBMJSSE2 1.7 jar

Comment: what's your java -fullversion output? Why are you referring to a specific IBMJSSE jar?

Comment: Be sure the JVM supports SSLv3 protocol.  And RC4 and 3DES ciphers are supported.   Most resent JVMs will have all that disabled.

Answer (score 0):

adding enabledCiphers="SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA" attribute in my ssl tag of server.xml file this issue get resolved.

```
<ssl id="defaultSSLConfig" keyStoreRef="defaultKeyStore" trustStoreRef="defaultTrustStore" 
     clientAuthenticationSupported="true" enabledCiphers="SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"/>
```

Comment: That's a relatively weak cipher. I wouldn't close the book on this issue.